# "No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I am attempting to update my android application to look better for tablets running Honeycomb. As such, I am targeting version 11 of the SDK (my minSdkVersion = 4). This adds the Honeycomb theme to my app, making it look better. However, I have no way to access my menu options. So, I am attempting to add my menu items as an action bar item with the following in the file in my /res/menu/ folder:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

However, I get the following error:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

I tried altering my minSdkVersion number to 11 to see if it would work, but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I immediately thought it was because showAsAction was added in API level 11, but you've taken that into consideration it seems.

Comment: That's what I had thought, which is why I added it. But, since I am developing in Eclipse, I needed to change my entire project target to #11, as Jason suggested below.

Comment: I got this error when I changed my project target to version 8. It turns out `showAsAction` was mentioned in the XML files when the target was higher, so I simply removed that line from the XMLs that gave the error and it solved the issue.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you are building with Eclipse, make sure your project's build target is set to Honeycomb too.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Much appreciated. 

Would you happen to know why nothing is showing up in my action bar, even with this code in place?

Comment: It should show. If not, create another question with your code.

Comment: You'll also need to do a clean after you change the build target.

Comment: Honeycomb  = API level 11 = Android 3.0.x

Answer (score 34):

remove `android:showAsAction="never"` from `res/menu` folder from every xml file.

Comment: Why should that be necessary?  android:showAsAction="never" can actually come in handy sometimes.

Comment: Although this wasn't the desired action, it was the best temporary solution.  I imported the android-support-v7-appcompat.jar, but it wasn't loading properly until I removed the android:showAsAction="never" lines from my XMLs, deleted the gen folder, cleaned the project, and rebuilt.  After I had a build without errors, I could add the android:showAsAction="never" back into my XMLs without errors.

Answer (score 22):

all above fix may not work in **android studio** .if you are using **ANDROID STUDIO**...... use this fix

add

`xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

in menu tag instead of

`xmlns:compat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

in **menu** tag.

Answer (score 16):

Add "**android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**" to Android Private Libraries

Answer (score 15):

Add `compat` library compilation to the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is related to AppCompat library. With it, you have

```
xmlns:appname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and possibly:

```
appname:showAsAction="never"
```

in menu.xml file.

Without the lib, you can only have:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

and my app works with menu both on Android 4.3 and 2.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Check your compileSdkVersion on app build.gradle. Set it to 21:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

Answer (score 0):

go to gradle and then to app.buildgradle then set compileSDKVersion to 21 and then if necessary the android studio will download some files

Answer (score 0):

From answer that was removed due to being written in Spanish:

All of the above fixes may not work in android studio. If you are using ANDROID STUDIO please use the following fix.

Use

```
xmlns: compat = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

on the menu label instead of

```
xmlns: compat = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```