# Eclipse Project Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, syntax, error-handling

I am working on the Bluetooth Chat from the Android Developer site in
Eclipse IDE.  I am using Android 2.1 and changed the Action Bar to
display Toast messages instead and am only working with Secure
connections.

I have three classes under the same package called BluetoothChat,
BluetoothChatService, and DeviceListActivity and the project name is
BluetoothCh.

Two of the files had errors that I fixed.  They were saved and are
clear of the red x that previously marked both .java files.  All of
the other files are clear of errors as well.  However, the main
Android project folder still contains a red x, and Eclipse is not
allowing a run or debug of the application because of errors in
the project.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this?  Any advice is very much
appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to clean the project?

Comment: try checking Problems and Console views - there could be some info about the error(s)

Comment: When I clean the project it now gives me errors that R cannot be resolved as a variable.  Where should I go from here?

Comment: does yout project's gen directory contains R.java? If yes then have you imported it in your class?

Answer (score 4):

1. Refresh the project then clean the project.
2. Delete the error in the "Problems" tab.
3. Right click the project->Android->Clean project properties (or whatever it is).

Comment: Where may I find the "Problems" tab?

Comment: Eclipse->Window->Show View->Problems.  It should pop in at the bottom.

Comment: Just found the Problems tab.  But after cleaning my project it now says that R cannot be resolved as a variable, for instance, when I get strings from different files by R.string.title_connecting.  When I import R (android) then it does not recognize my xml files and id's.  Any advice?  Thank you for all of the help!

Comment: Once you fix the original problem the R should be regenerated (though, you may have to refresh the project to trigger it).  Does the Problems tab tell you what the original problem is?

Comment: In the Console I am receiving two main errors several times including:[2011-06-22 08:14:30 - BluetoothChat] W/ResourceType( 5768): Bad XML block: header size 62 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0   AND   [2011-06-22 08:14:30 - BluetoothChat] C:\Documents and Settings\shudya1\workspace\BluetoothChat\res\menu\option_menu.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

Comment: Google found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260686/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-showasaction-in-package-android

Comment: Thank you! I am currently in the middle of debugging the application, since the application is not successfully connecting to another device.  Hopefully I will be able to find the root of this error in debugging.  Thank you for all of your time and help!

Comment: @Angelina If this answered your question, please click the checkmark beside my answer to tell others that this is the accepted reply.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and rebuild it see if the X mark still persists.

Answer (score 0):

"When I clean the project it now gives me errors that R cannot be resolved as a variable. Where should I go from here?"

It sounds like you have an error in your code somewhere. You need to find out where the error is (what file and line) and fix it. This can be done with the problems tab in eclipse. It should tell you the description, file, path, line, and type of error you are getting.