# Error in changing the android API level?

Tags: android

when i am creating new project i added API level 14 , i have completed my application and i want to change the API level to 10 ,

i am getting and error in resources-->values-v11--> style.xml 
i.e `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.`

in resources-->values-v14--> style.xml

i.e  `error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.`

i dint understood this can any one explain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These themes are available in API level 11 or higher so it will not work.because you are using API level 10.

refer this link- 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: what is the solution now ? that to be display in below that API level

Comment: how to find the themes of API level 10 , and can i delete those folders ?

Comment: How did that answer solve the problem? I set android:targetSdkVersion="11" in my Manifest file and I still get the problem. I added all the android.jar files from APIs 8 to 16 to my project. Error is very resilient :(

Comment: @shailenTJ setting the target in the manifest does not affect the way you code builds. I persume you're using Eclipse - so please set your Android build target to anything >= Android 4.0.

(Project properties -> Android -> Project build target).

Answer (score 8):

Following [ankita gahoi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474419/ankita-gahoi)'s advice, I searched a little further and solved the problem.

Try this:

Delete the folders 'values-11' and 'values-14' (if any of them exist). Then, if this error shows up in the console window:

```
 "No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'"
```

Read the answers to these questions: 
["No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260686/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-showasaction-in-package-android) (Jason Hanley's)

[How to change target build on Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342739/how-to-change-target-build-on-android-project) (Alan Will's)

My build target was already set to the right Android version, so I set it to 'Google APIs' and then back to the former target.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on a specific case where one of the Android Library Projects had its reference SDK set to API 9. What got me confused was that the Error Log showed the name of the project with the correct settings, and not the problematic one.

Answer (score -1):

go to values-v11--> style.xml. replace code  :

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

by   code :

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Comment: I formatted the code blocks to be visible but cannot see any difference there.