# Eclipse Android - Cant change build path to fix error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.myapp'

Tags: android, eclipse

Im getting this error:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.myapp' add.xml /myapp/res/menu
```

But I cant figure out how to fix it. I didn't have this error on my previous computer which ran this package fine. 
I have looked at some fixes on here which so far haven't worked, for example, I cant change build path: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMu0p.jpg)

maybe there is something else I should try? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260686/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-showasaction-in-package-android)

Comment: there ar amny similar issues on StackOverflow. Please google it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260686/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-showasaction-in-package-android